# Setting the focus on the first input field in a table

Tags: angular

This is how I set the focus on a field in Angular 6. First, I declare the field in HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="myfield" [(ngModel)]="myfield" id="myfield" #focusMe />
```

Then in Javascript:

```
@ViewChild('focusMe') focusMe: ElementRef;

.....

this.focusMe.nativeElement.focus();
```

But I have a table and I need the focus on the first element; I don't know how to set `#focusMe`:

```
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let f of fields; let i = index">
            <td>
                {{f.name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="field{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="f.value" 
                    id="field{{i}}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

How to set the focus on the first input field?

Comment: Have you tried the `autofocus` attribute? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#autofocus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somewhat inefficient, but you can use the `first` property of `@ViewChildren`:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let f of fields; let i = index">
    <td>
      {{f.name}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <input #focusMe type="text" name="field{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="f.value" id="field{{i}}" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
@ViewChildren('focusMe') focusMe: QueryList<HTMLInputElement>;

.....

this.focusMe.first.nativeElement.focus();
```